# how to make group by device time stamp with the sum with linq in C#

Tags: c#, linq

how to get group by devicetimestamp and show sum .

linq query

```
List<Total_Power> Total_PowerList = db.Total_Power.Where(u => u.DeviceImei == RS.DeviceImei && (u.DeviceTimeStamp >= RS.FromDate && u.DeviceTimeStamp <= RS.ToDate)).OrderByDescending(u => u.DeviceTimeStamp).ToList();
   Total_PowerList = from s in Total_PowerList
                          group s by new { date = new DateTime(s.DeviceTimeStamp.Date) } into g
                          select new
                          {
                              read_date = g.Key.date,
                              T1 = g.Sum(x => x.KWH),
                              T2 = g.Sum(x => x.KWH)
                          };
```

Exp op
Date KWH KWHCount

datatype of KWH is float

sample data

```
DeviceTimeStamp          KWH
2020-12-05 12:30:15.000 62869.04
2020-12-05 12:15:16.000 62840.59
2020-12-05 12:00:16.000 62811.74
2020-12-05 11:45:22.000 62778.39

Exp op
DeviceTimeStamp          KWH       KWHConsumption
2020-12-05              62869.04   57.3
```

Comment: Hi, Where is your try?

Comment: db.Total_Power.GroupBy(x => x.DeviceTimeStamp.Date).ToList();
i tried like this but its giving error at .Date

Comment: @Vinod look at the duplicate

Comment: but that was not group by datetime field. i have group by datetime field. i want to find day wise energy consumption. i have edited my question. can u look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By expected output second value isn't Sum but Max (end state of the day).

I don't know what is the third value in the expected result. I think it is difference between daily max KWH and min KWH but I'm not sure because value in expected output doesn't match the difference. The value 57.3 corresponds to the Max / Min difference after 12 o'clock (only PM).

Try use Linq similar to this:

```
var result = data
    .GroupBy(
        i => i.DeviceTimeStamp.Date,
        (timeStamp, dayilyData) => new { timeStamp, dayilyData })
    .Select(i => new
        {
            i.timeStamp,
            finalState = i.dayilyData.Max(x => x.KWH),
            consuption = (i.dayilyData.Max(x => x.KWH) - i.dayilyData.Min(x => x.KWH)) })
    .ToList();
```